# Less cumbersome way to parse XML attributes with nested tags

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm currently trying to parse an XML file with baseball scores. The file stores all the information in attributes which is giving me a little trouble. Here is an example of the setup.

```
<game id="2016/07/20/atlmlb-cinmlb-1" venue="Great American Ball Park">
    <linescore>
         <inning away="1" home="0"/>
         <r away="3" home="6" diff="3"/>
         <h away="9" home="12"/>
    </linescore>
    <winning_pitcher id="543101" last="test" first="bob">
    <losing_pitcher id="449173" last="test" first="joe">
 </game>
```

What I have so far is:

```
NamedNodeMap ga= game.getAttributes();
Node stadium = ga.getNamedItem("venue");
String stad = stadium.getNodeValue();

NodeList linescore = game.getChildNodes();
NamedNodeMap ls = linescore.item(3).getAttributes();
....
```

This would be fine if everything was stored in a game attribute, but since a lot of it is nested, it's becoming cumbersome to have to create a nodelist for child attributes, and then repeat over again, especially when I'm trying to grab 20-30 stats. Is there an easier way to say, grab the home score from `<r>`, the winning pitcher first name and losing pitcher first name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPaths make XML access much less cumbersome:

> Is there an easier way to say, grab the home score from `<r>`

```
/game/linescore/r/@home
```

> the winning pitcher first name

```
/game/winning_pitcher/@first
```

> and losing pitcher first name

```
/game/losing_pitcher/@first
```

Use the above XPaths combined with [How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2811001/290085).

Comment: Great I'll take a look at that.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Jackson's extention for XML: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml, it allows you to serialize/deserialize XML into POJO's

Comment: I ended up going with XPATH for what I had to do, but thanks for the suggestion. If I had done JSON I probably would have tried to use Jacksons as it seems to be the best.